# javafx checkbox clicked while key pressed will not change state

Tags: javafx, checkbox, keyevent

I have a very simple problem, which I can't find in any other posts :

In javafx15 / java15.0.1, I am trying to click a Checkbox while pressing, for example, the CONTROL key... State is not changing.

I tried to catch the key (with a key event on the checkbox), and I do catch the control key pressed... But state of checkbox just does not change if a key is pressed simultaniously.

How to get this to just work in a transparent way ?

Here is a most basic simple code to illustate the problem :

```
package checkboxkeypressed;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckboxWhileKeyPressedNotWorking extends Application {

    private CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        checkbox.setText("Click me while pressing a key...");
        Scene scene = new Scene(checkbox, 200, 50);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Checkbox cannot be ticked while a key is pressed !!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you check `ButtonBehavior` class, you will find a boolean called `keyDown`. They are mentioning this: _As long as keyDown is true, we are also armed, and will ignore mouse events related to arming._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improving on the [solution offered by  etuygar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465102/3992939):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckboxWhileKeyPressedNotWorking extends Application {

    private final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
    private boolean isControlKeyDown = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        checkbox.setText("Click me while pressing <CNTRL> key");
        checkbox.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            if(isControlKeyDown){
                checkbox.fire(); //change check box state
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(checkbox, 300, 50);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
            isControlKeyDown = keyEvent.isControlDown();
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent -> {
            isControlKeyDown = keyEvent.isControlDown();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to use `checkbox.fire()` instead of `checkbox.setSelected(! checkbox.isSelected());`? If the `CheckBox` allows `indeterminate` state, manually toggling the state is not going to show the expected behavior.

Comment: @MissChanandlerBong `checkbox.fire()` is indeed a better option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
package checkboxkeypressed;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckboxWhileKeyPressedNotWorking extends Application {

private CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

private boolean ctrlOk, lastState;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    
    checkbox.setText("Click me while pressing a key...");
    Scene scene = new Scene(checkbox, 200, 50);

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.CONTROL) ctrlOk = true;      
    });

    
    
    scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.CONTROL) ctrlOk = false;     
    });

    
    
    checkbox.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        
        if (!ctrlOk) {
            checkbox.setSelected(lastState);
        } else {
            checkbox.setSelected(!checkbox.isSelected());
            lastState = checkbox.isSelected();
        }

    });
    
    

    primaryStage.setTitle("Checkbox cannot be ticked while a key is pressed !!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: You may want to add the `setOnMouseClicked` to the scene to detect <CNTRL> key down in case it was pressed outside the `checkbox`. Also there is not need to save the last state of the `CheckBox`.  You can toggle it by `checkbox.setSelected(! checkbox.isSelected());`

Comment: Or better still `checkbox.fire()` as @MissChanandlerBong proposed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you soooooo much @miss-chanandler-bong !

So would this answer be ok ? I'm forcing the checkbox to be armed, when armed is changing...

```
package checkboxkeypressed;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckboxWhileKeyPressed extends Application {

    private CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        checkbox.setText("Click me while pressing a key...");

        checkbox.armedProperty().addListener(changeListener -> checkbox.arm());
        checkbox.arm();
        checkbox.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> processKeyPressed(keyEvent));
        Scene scene = new Scene(checkbox, 200, 50);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Checkbox CAN NOW be ticked while a key is pressed !!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void processKeyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.CONTROL)) {
            System.out.println("Key IS control");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Key IS NOT control : '" + keyEvent.getCode().getName() + "'");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Preventing actions when another key is pressed is the default behavior, so I think implementing a CheckBox Behavior is the correct way to go.